# To implement the method search in Composed UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have used a `UITableView` in my application. In that, instead of default `UITableView`, I used a composed one using `UILabels`.

I have  a list of objects and in each of the table rows I have 6 labels like:

```
1st label --Customername 
2nd label --Curresponding customername of the object
3rd label --CustomerID
4th label --Curresponding customeID of the object
5th label --Description
6th label --Curresponding description of the object
```

In this how can I implement search method for a particular criteria, say `CustomerName`?

Comment: where you are taken the label values means in array or dictionary?

Comment: I have used UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource to display the values of the label.So in cellForRowAtIndexPath those labels will be loaded.

If you are asking about the search method,I think I will go for array

Answer (score 0):

Add a searchBar on top of UITableView , and using the SearchButtonClicked delegate of the searchBar implement the searching functionality , example if user searched for any keyword , you catch the keyword by searchBar.text in the searchBarButtopnClicked delegate in your class . Now search that name into the Array (from which you are populating the UITableView ) . If you found any object resembling with the searched keyword reload the UITableView else give a UIAlertView that "No Item Matched"